# Phase difference in reflection coefficient between S and P polarisation at normal incidence?

Tags: optics

Below we have the Fresnel Equation at an interface for S and P polarisation:
\begin{align}
 r^s &= \frac{n_0 \cos{\theta_0}-n_1\cos{\theta_1}}{n_0\cos{\theta_0} + n_1\cos{\theta_1}} \quad\quad t^s = \frac{2n_1\cos{\theta_0}}{n_0\cos{\theta_0} + n_1\cos{\theta_1}}\\  r^p&= \frac{n_1 \cos{\theta_0}-n_0\cos{\theta_1}}{n_1\cos{\theta_0} + n_0\cos{\theta_1}}\quad\quad t^p = \frac{2n_1\cos{\theta_0}}{n_1\cos{\theta_0} + n_0\cos{\theta_1}} 
\end{align}
When light approaches the interface at normal incidence these equations simplify to:
\begin{align}
 r^s &= \frac{n_0 -n_1}{n_0 + n_1} \quad\quad t^s = \frac{2n_1}{n_0 + n_1}\\  r^p&= \frac{n_1 -n_0}{n_1 + n_0}\quad\quad t^p = \frac{2n_1}{n_1 + n_0} 
\end{align}

When we apply this to an example where we have an aluminium mirror with refractive index, for example, of 0.93878 + i6.4195.

This would lead for S polarisation to a reflection coefficient -0.9138 - 0.2855i, leading to reflectivity of 95% but a phase shift of -0.90$\pi$.
However, for P polarisation a reflection coefficient  0.9138 + 0.2855i is found, leading to the same reflectivity but a phase shift of 0.09$\pi$.

Since we come in under normal incidence, why would the orientation of the polarisation matter? The polarisation S and P are both parallel with the surface, so this would mean if I rotate the mirror I would change the phase of the reflected beam? How does this make sense? What am I missing?

Edit: this also the case for dielectric matter (i.e. real $n$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained fairly well in the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations). Your paradox just arises from the need for a sign convention when deriving the Fresnel conditions, namely that a positive reflection coefficient means the transverse wave component keeps the same direction. For s-polarised light that is the E-field, but for p-polarised light it is the H-field.

Hence a positive $r$ for p-polarised light means no phase change for the H-field, but since the reflected wave travels opposite to the incident wave, the E-field must flip.

Comment: So the reflection coeff. from the fresnel equations only apply on the transverse wave component?

Comment: @SjonTeflon they are applied to the E-field. The H-field follows from the properties of EM waves. However, there has to be a definition of what a positive r means.